# Merge into master breaking code without conflict

Tags: git, github

We work with a lot of branches and before each merge into master >1h of automated tests (e.g. travis) need to pass on pull requests. This means not every branch can be updated to latest master before merge. 
Now consider code includes function *f* in library L.

1. Pull request A removes *f* from L
2. Pull request B uses *f* from L in another file
3. A is merged into master
4. B has no git conflicts, but is based on a master before A was merged, therefore tests pass and B is merged

Now we clearly have a broken master, because we use a function that does not exist. Regarding this I have two questions:

1. Is there a name for this scenario, I've tried googling it with no luck and silent conflict appears to mean something else.
2. How to solve this problem in general without disrupting the existing workflow (maybe introduce something new to it, but not take away)?

Comment: Every branch *could* be updated, but you don’t want to wait for hours of tests—solution: make your tests faster.

Comment: Not an option for a big product

Comment: An hour of testing? Yeah there's something wrong with either the tests themselves or the way your test suite is structured.

Comment: You need to test the *merged code*, not the branch by itself, to allow or block a PR.

Comment: I'm guessing the "integration" part of "continuous integration" slipped your attention, then?  Testing un-integrated code won't tell you what happens when you integrate it. Merge to a QA branch, fast forward master to that when it passes or reset the QA branch if the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether a particular file system tree meets some criteria (including whether it compiles), you must perform some sort of test that it does so.

In this case, the Git tree that you want to test is the one created by merging a particular feature branch and the latest master.  While the hash of the commit will change depending on timestamps, the Git tree will remain the same if you perform identical merges.  You can use this optimization when performing tests, skipping tests that you know have already passed for a given tree.

You could adjust your CI system to perform some sort of quick compile test if your code is compiled and reserve the in-depth testing for only the initial push.  However, there isn't any way to avoid doing some sort of test for your code if you want to know whether a particular state (in this case, a given tree) will meet your requirements (whether it works).  Diff parsing is not likely to be a fruitful endeavor here, since there are many kinds of errors it won't detect.

As others have mentioned, it is possible to improve the speed of tests.  Many large organizations with complex codebases parallelize their tests so that they can be run within a reasonable amount of time.  If there is redundant state (such as OS setup) that's expensive, you could create a base image (e.g., with Vagrant or Docker) and then build your tests on top of that, saving time.

You could also just take the risk that the commit will be broken, since in many cases it won't suffer from these situations.  However, if you want to avoid that at all costs, you need to perform some sort of test.